# Multiple RewriteRules in htaccess to same file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Okay so I am really rookie in htaccess and everything I do is kind of trial and error.

I have to make a couple of landingpages for my website and need to control the URL’s in htaccess so they look nice for google etc.

```
#Landingpages ex.
RewriteRule ^colors/ article.php
RewriteRule ^sizes/ article.php
RewriteRule ^categories/ article.php
```

So when I enter the url [www.domain.com/colors](http://www.domain.com/colors) it goes to article.php where I can pick up the url with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and get ‘/colors’ to make a lookup in my DB

I will properly have 25 of these.

I also want to do /colors/green and use that as key for my db, but I don’t want to add a RewriteRule for that like below, because then I would have so many

```
RewriteRule ^colors/green article.php
```

NB: I also have other pages that I dont want to go article.php like /basket or /profile, etc.

What is the best way to do the above?

Can I make it in one RewriteRule?

Can I send the word ex. Colors as a get parameter to article.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex alternation and capture group to capture a value from URI that can be passed as `GET` parameter:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(colors(?:/green)?|sizes|categories)/ article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes it seem to work as it should, thank you. But if i write /colors/green the id parameter only contains /colors and not /colors/green. But i can get that another way :)

Comment: I added handling of `/colors/green` in my rule